# R: Operate on a list and store output in a new list

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes, would like to operate on the list and store output in a new dataframe. specifically, I want to keep path and month column while make the first row of data column 1, and the rest of rows as the result of division between k and k-1 row.

Sample Data

```
myList2 <- list()
myList2[[1]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,3,5,6,7), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList2[[2]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(2,2,2,1,2,3,4,6,5), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList2[[3]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(3,3,3,1,2,3,6,7,6), nrow=3, ncol=3))
colnames <- c("path","month", "data")
myList2<-lapply(myList2, setNames,colnames)
print(myList2)
```

```
> print(myList2)
[[1]]
  path month data
1    1     1    5
2    1     2    6
3    1     3    7

[[2]]
  path month data
1    2     1    4
2    2     2    6
3    2     3    5

[[3]]
  path month data
1    3     1    6
2    3     2    7
3    3     3    6
```

What I tried so far:

```
x <- list()
x <- for (i in 1:length(myList2))
{
for (k in 2:length(myList2[i]))
{
x[[i]][1] <- 1
x[[i]][k] <- myList2[[i]][k]/myList2[[i]][k-1]
}
}
```

Desired Result:

```
myList <- list()
myList[[1]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,3,1,5/6,6/7), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList[[2]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(2,2,2,1,2,3,1,4/6,5/6), nrow=3, ncol=3))
myList[[3]]<- as.data.frame(matrix(c(3,3,3,1,2,3,1,6/7,7/6), nrow=3, ncol=3))
colnames <- c("path","month", "data")
myList<-lapply(myList, setNames,colnames)
print(myList)
```

```
> print(myList)
[[1]]
  path month      data
1    1     1 1.0000000
2    1     2 0.8333333
3    1     3 0.8571429

[[2]]
  path month      data
1    2     1 1.0000000
2    2     2 0.6666667
3    2     3 0.8333333

[[3]]
  path month      data
1    3     1 1.0000000
2    3     2 0.8571429
3    3     3 1.1666667
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` with `map` and `mutate` the 'data' by dividing the column with the `lead` of the column and readjust the output by conccatenating 1 at the beginning

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(myList2, ~ .x %>%
                   mutate(data = c(1, na.omit(data/lead(data)))))
```

---

or with `base R` using the same logic

```
lapply(myList2, transform, data = c(1, data[-length(data)]/data[-1]))
#[[1]]
#  path month      data
#1    1     1 1.0000000
#2    1     2 0.8333333
#3    1     3 0.8571429

#[[2]]
#  path month      data
#1    2     1 1.0000000
#2    2     2 0.6666667
#3    2     3 1.2000000

#[[3]]
#  path month      data
#1    3     1 1.0000000
#2    3     2 0.8571429
#3    3     3 1.1666667
```